# Sharing simple data between 2 Android apps on the same device

Tags: android

I'm developing 2 Android apps that will be deployed on the same device and I'd like them to share an authentication token (string) to access a web API.

I know the WORLD_READABLE_MODE for the SharedPreferences class is deprecated and I don't want to develop a ContentProvider for such a simple job (also, this is not really "content" that I'm trying to share).

Any tips on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Either these two apps are guaranteed to be installed/uninstalled always as a pair, or they are not. If they are, have just one app. If, however, the user might have either App A, or App B, or both App A *and* App B, then you *don't* want to "share" this token, at least based on how I am interpreting "share" from your possible solutions. After all, if App A is the one with the token, and the user later uninstalls App A, App B is then screwed if it was relying on A's copy of the token. Instead, IMHO, you want to *sync* the token, so if one app already has the token, the other app can pick it up.

Comment: So, if an app does not have the token, have it briefly bind to a service in the other app and ask "hey, do *you* have the token?". For ongoing updates, point-to-point "broadcasts" could allow one app to let the other app know about a changed token.

Comment: This is more like the "sync" idea. They are 2 independent apps with login screens. But if a user has already logged in app A, I'd like app B to take advantage of it. And vice-versa.

Comment: Yeah, then I'd lean towards bound service for pulling an existing token and point-to-point broadcasts for pushing a token change. IPC mechanisms are your only options for sharing this data securely. `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is fairly literal; any app knowing that the file exists could go read it.

Answer (score -1):

make use of android intent with custom action like below.
You need to define IntentFilter for filtering the custom action in your other app activities.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_CUSTOM_TOKEN);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text_token");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Reflect and upvote if this is useful for the cause.

Comment: Hi! That's not the case I'm sending data to any app. It's the opposite. An app will pull one string from another.

Comment: Send BroadCast from app2 with custom action. After receiving it in app1, check token value & send to app2 with another broadcast and custom action. All this can happen in background. <br />With custom action it is not possible that system will deliver broadcast to un-intended app.